# why is this error been thrown "Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'Ben'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

xammp is throwing this error despite having all the permissions granted for the root user.
I have tried creating a new user with all permissions granted too but the same error was thrown. I have also tried creating a new project as I have seen was the solution to a question posted here but it didn't work for me either.

Here are the scripts and a screenshot showing my config.

```
<?php

require 'constants.php';

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_NAME, DB_PASS);

if ($conn-> connect_error){
    die('Database error:' .$conn->connect_error);
}
```

the constants file:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "user-verification");
?>
```

[image: Users overview screenshot]

Comment: Try the loopback address "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost". Sometimes that does make a difference. Why ever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Allow No Password to be true. Then you can log in without a password. Open setup configuration by going on path-to-phpmyadmin/**setup**

[Add New Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig6ud.png)

[Check allow no password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIwM7.png)

Apply and download this configuration file and then copy and paste it to the root folder of PHPMyAdmin.

If you already have the **config.inc.php** file in the PHPMyAdmin root folder. Open that file in any text editor and below line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`

I think that might help you.

Comment: Better to suggest not logging in as root from a php application. OP should make another mysql account and have the application use that. It's better for security, even on a development machine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).